# Matching permutations of columns in two data sets

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, csv, permutation

I have two sets of data (csv files) which contain occurences of key database columns and the number of times they appear. (original database tables are no longer available)

For example:

set 1

```
column 1  column 2  column 3  count
1         2         3         100
1         2         2         200
3         1         1         700
```

set 2

```
column 1  column 2  column 3  count
1         2         3         500
1         2         2         133
1         1         1         100
```

I need some way to compare the two tables to tell me if there is a combination in set 1 that is not present in set 2.

I'm thinking of writing a script which will loop through set one with a nested loop for set 2 but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Open to suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

To get the combinations in table2 that are not in table1:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table_1
except
select col1, col2, col3
from table_2;
```

To get the combinations in table1 that are not in table2:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table_2
except 
select col1, col2, col3
from table_1;
```

To get both in one statement:

```
(
  select col1, col2, col3
  from table_1
  except
  select col1, col2, col3
  from table_2
)
union all
(
  select col1, col2, col3
  from table_2
  except
  select col1, col2, col3
  from table_1
);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/71566/1

Answer (score 1):

No loops please :)

```
select t1.* 
from t1 left join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3
where t2.col1 is null
```

Left joins create nulls where no record is found.  Left join t1 to t2 and all times that t2 is null means a record in t1 has no match in t2.

Change this to right join and where t1.col1 is null and you'll see all of t2 not in t1 as well.